# Unable to install Ubuntu 12.10 on Windows XP Professional

Tags: 12.10, wubi, windows-xp, installation

The message that I get is: `C;\docu~1\user\locals~1\temp\wubi12.10rev273log`

By opening this text file, I read that some picture could not be loaded.

What am I to do? Stay on Windows?

Answer (score 1):

The file is probably saying the Ubuntu ISO *image* could not be loaded. [That kind of image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_image) is not a picture--it is a representation of data on a disk.

You have two options:

1. Investigate why the problem is happening and fix the cause.
2. Work around the problem.

For *1*, you need to provide much more information:

- The complete and exact error message.
- The entire text from the log file (can be provided at http://paste.ubuntu.com if it's too big to include in your question).

Feel free to provide that information by editing your question. However, you may be able to **work around the problem**:

1. Download the appropriate ISO image. Go to the Ubuntu website and click [the option to download Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop). Get the regular version, *not* the Windows installer.
2. Put the big file (the ISO image) you downloaded in a folder. Put `wubi.exe` (the Windows installer) in the folder too. Don't have anything else in the folder.
3. Run `wubi.exe` (the one in that folder). It will automatically identify the ISO image and use it, so it won't have to download a new one.

Make sure to get the same version of Ubuntu that you specified when you downloaded the Windows installer (for example, if you downloaded the Windows installer for Ubuntu 12.10, make sure to get a 12.10 ISO as well).

**If you are already doing this**, or if you downloaded an ISO image and burned it to a CD/DVD or wrote it to a USB flash drive and are **attempting to install installing Wubi (i.e., Ubuntu with the Windows installer) off the CD/DVD/USB**, then probably:

- the ISO image you downloaded is bad, perhaps corrupted during download ([MD5 test](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) it and if it's bad download a new one), *or*
- the burn/write was bad and your CD/DVD/USB is corrupted (try writing it again).